# Why are Cousin problems so relevant?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, meromorphic-functions, line-bundles

It is known that Cousin problems are especially relevant in determining if a meromorphic function can be expressed as a quotient of two holomorphic functions. Indeed:

> > **Theorem 1** Let $X$ a complex, connected variety, such that the second Cousin problem is satisfied. Then every meromorphic function is the quotient of two holomorphic functions on $X$, such that the germs of $f$ and $g$ do not have any common divisor.

In literature, this result is usually reported after

> > **Theorem 2** Let $\phi$ a meromorphic function on a complex, connected variety $X$. Then, there exists a line bundle $L \to X$ and two sections $s_0, s_1$ of $L$ such that $\phi = s_1/s_0$.

I guess my question is: how does Theorem 1 adds any new information to Theorem 2? Indeed, every section of a line bundle is a holomorphic function on $X$ already: why would it be of any benefit for a meromorphic function to be expressed as a quotient of holomorphic functions which are not sections of a bundle in general?

Comment: It is much easier to work directly with holomorphic functions than to keep track different (note that your Theorem 2 doesn't rule out $L$ nontrivial) line bundles for different $\phi$.

Comment: Actually you can prove that if you have a finite set of meromorphic functions there exists a line bundle $L$ such that every meromorphic functions can be expressed as a quotient of sections of $L$

Comment: Huh? How is a section of a nontrivial line bundle a holomorphic function? For starters, when $X$ is compact, the only holomorphic functions are constants.